# unable to make connection using mongosqld to remote mongodb via mongodb BI connctor

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, mongodb-biconnector

I have a remote mongodb server running, I dont have control over it. I have given read credential for it to use it in tableau for reporting.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.14\bin>mongosqld --mongo-uri "mongodb://<HOST NAM>:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=rs0" --auth --mongo-authenticationSource=admin -u <userid> -p <password> --schemaDirectory "C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Connector for BI/2.14/bin/schema" --mongo-ssl --addr=0.0.0.0:3307
```

I am getting below error.

```
2023-02-20T16:54:24.050+0530 E NETWORK    [initandlisten] unable to load MongoDB information: failed to create admin session for loading server cluster information: unable to execute command: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Servers: [{ Addr: <host>:27017, Type: Unknown, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() error occured during connection handshake: read tcp **myipaddress**:60709-><**host**>:27017: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. }, ] }
```

Can somebody point me in right direction?